WaitForEndOfFrame in a loop is not updating the inspector
My code has a function
void Generate()
{
    for(...)
    {

        while(...)
        {
        ...
        }
        StartCoroutine(waitFrame());
        Debug.Log(time);
    }
}



The generate function is called once in the Update() function when I press down a key.
I added the IEnumerator waitFrame() to avoid unity crashing since i'm going through a lot of data.
I wanted to see how much time each while loop took to complete by writing the time in the console with the Debug.Log(time); above, where time is updated in Update(). However nothing is writen in the console until the end of the loop, and the value of time is equal to 0 for each of the loops.
I'm guessing the loops in Generate() update independently from Update() as they would without the WaitForFrame, since a loop would normally execute within 1 frame.
My question is how can I debug updated values or change values in the inspector, like the time each while loop takes inside the for loop, inside my Generate() function containing a StartCoroutine(WaitForEndOfFrame);

You have not implemented your wait correctly.
StartCoroutine(waitFrame());

This line says "start a coroutine, then immediately continue and run the next line as you normally would".
The coroutine you started might wait a frame, but the code that started it does not, because you did not tell it to do so.
To make your Generate function something that can be suspended and wait a frame, it needs to be an IEnumerator or async function itself. Just calling an IEnumerator function does not bestow its suspend-ability on the calling function, or suspend it until the coroutine it started finishes.
Here's a version that would work:
void Generate() {
    StartCoroutine(GeneratorLoop());
}

IEnumerator GeneratorLoop() {
    for (...) {
        var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        while (...) {
            ...
        }

        Debug.Log(timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

        // Suspend and resume next frame.
        yield return null;
    }
}

